# Check if Yahoo Messenger is installed

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to find out if a user has Yahoo Messenger installed, using javascript?

I'm trying to better handle ymsgr: links, as IE throws a cryptic error if YM is not installed.

Comment: A better way to ask this would be 'can I, from JS, tell if IE has a handler for ysmsgr: protocol links?'  Asked like that you don't need to know what programs are installed and it's much more likely to be in the domain of the JS sandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript has no access to client OS to check if a program is installed or not.